# Looking for example Jasper Reports GenericElementPdfHandler implementation

Tags: jasper-reports, customization, ireport

I'm looking for any examples anyone may have of a Jasper Reports implementation of a GenericElementPdfHandler.  The mapping one in the code just produces an image and delegates back to the JRPdfExporter class.  I'm looking for something more text-based, as I need to perform logic similar to what's in JRPdfExporter.setHyperlinkInfo().  The code in the demo directory is related to HTML and doesn't seem to apply to my use case.

Specifically, I'm looking to implement a generic handler that allows me to place clickable elements in my PDF, which make calls to Adobe JavaScript functions when clicked.  Jasper Reports provides a way to fire PDF logic when the document is opened, but not in response to element click events.

I would appreciate any examples anyone can share, or any helpful resources.  All of my web searching has turned up nothing useful.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get some help from one of the developers on the Jaspser community site.  Some additional information can be found here:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/801396/embedding-print-page-control-pdf